# Is the definition $\left(\mathcal{K}_{l}\right)_{mn}=\epsilon_{lmn}$ for the generators of $SO(3)$ in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, conventions, rotation, lie-algebra

Note: I do not believe this is simply a matter of convention regarding what is considered a positive angle, handedness of the coordinates, nor the ordering of matrix multiplication for vector operations.  All of those are standard in other parts of MTW.

**My question: is my modified definition a correct.  Or is that given by MTW correct?**

In exercise 9.13 of Gravitation, by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, the component definition of the generator matrices of the rotation group is given as $\left(\mathcal{K}_{l}\right)_{mn}=\epsilon_{lmn},$ where $\epsilon_{lmn}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. This appears to be incorrect.  I propose that the definition should be $\left(\mathcal{K}_{l}\right)_{mn}=-\epsilon_{lmn}$

Unless my mind is playing tricks on me, the definition given by MTW results in

$$\mathcal{K}_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix};\mathcal{K}_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix};\mathcal{K}_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Something called the *complex structure* of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is introduced in [Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica, Third Edition, by Alfred Gray, Elsa Abbena, Simon Salamon](https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=6280).  It is defined as $\mathcal{J}\left(p_1,p_2\right)=\left(-p_2,p_1\right),$ which is a rotation by $\pi/2$.  Its matrix $\mathcal{J}$ and whole number powers thereof are

$$\mathcal{J}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix};\mathcal{J}^{2}=-\mathcal{I};\mathcal{J}^{3}=-\mathcal{J};\mathcal{J}^{4}=\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{J}^{0}.$$

Raising $e$ to a matrix power is defined to be formally identical to the Taylor series expansion of $e^{x}.$ So if our matrix is $\theta\mathfrak{m},$ where $\theta$ is a scalar, we have

$$e^{\theta\mathfrak{m}}=\theta^{0}\mathfrak{m}^{0}+\theta\mathfrak{m}+\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}\mathfrak{m}^{2}+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{n}}{n!}\mathfrak{m}^{n}.$$

The familiar Taylor Series expansion of the complex exponential function is

$$e^{\theta\text{i}}=\left(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\theta^{4}}{4!}-\dots\right)+\mathrm{i}\left(\theta-\frac{\theta^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\theta^{5}}{5!}-\dots\right)
=\cos\theta+\mathrm{i}\sin\theta$$

Matching terms we see that

$$\begin{aligned}
e^{\mathcal{J}\theta}&=\mathcal{I}\left(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\theta^{4}}{4!}-\dots\right)+\mathcal{J}\left(\theta-\frac{\theta^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\theta^{5}}{5!}-\dots\right)\\
&=\mathcal{I}\cos\theta+\mathcal{J}\sin\theta\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\cos\theta+\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\sin\theta\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix},
\end{aligned}$$

which is a rotation in the Euclidean plane by $\theta$.

As can be seen in the screen capture below, the sub-matrices of the $\mathcal{K}_l$ formed of non-zero rows and columns, and the powers of those sub-matrices are equal to the matrix $\pm\mathcal{J},$ and its powers.

The exercise gives the definition

$$\mathcal{R}_{x}\left(\theta\right)\equiv\exp\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\theta\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{n}}{n!}\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\right)^{n},$$

and asks us to show that this is a rotation matrix which produces a rotation by $\theta$ about the $x$-axis. And similarly for the $y$- and $z$-axes.

To simplify things, we define

$$\mathcal{I}_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Thus we have

$$\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\right)^{0}=\mathcal{I};\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\right)^{1}=\mathcal{K}_{1};\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\right)^{2}=-\mathcal{I}_{1};\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\right)^{3}=-\mathcal{K}_{1};\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\right)^{4}=\mathcal{I}_{1}.$$

Using these to expand our exponential gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\exp\left(\mathcal{K}_{1}\theta\right)&=\mathcal{I}-\mathcal{I}_{1}+\mathcal{I}_{1}\left(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\theta^{4}}{4!}-\dots\right)+\mathcal{K}_{1}\left(\theta-\frac{\theta^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\theta^{5}}{5!}-\dots\right)\\
&=\mathcal{I}-\mathcal{I}_{1}+\mathcal{I}_{1}\cos\theta+\mathcal{K}_{1}\sin\theta\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos\theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sin\theta\\
0 & -\sin\theta & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
0 & -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}.$$

But this is a rotation about the $x$-axis by $-\theta.$  The other two matrices also produce rotations by $-\theta.$

$$
\exp\left(\mathcal{K}_{2}\theta\right)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}\\
\exp\left(\mathcal{K}_{3}\theta\right)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0\\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

[image]

Comment: What do you think is the standard direction of rotation in the xy plane: clockwise or anticlockwise? In the complex plane, multiplication by i is fixed by convention to give an anticlockwise rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinitesimal generators for $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ are a basis for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, which is the vector space of $3\times 3$ antisymmetric matrices with real entries.  As with any vector space, this basis is not unique - any linearly independent spanning set will do.

$(\mathcal K_l)_{mn}=\epsilon_{lmn}$ is obviously a valid choice for such a basis, as is your modified choice $(K'_l)_{mn}=-\epsilon_{lmn}$.  Using MTW's convention, the commutation relations$^\dagger$ for this basis are
$$[K_i,K_j]= -\epsilon_{ijk}K_k$$
while
$$[K'_i,K'_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}K'_k$$

Both of these are perfectly reasonable choices which correspond to precisely the same Lie algebra.  The generators $K_i$ can be thought of as generating infinitesimal clockwise (left-handed) rotations around the relevant axis, while $K'_i$ generate counterclockwise (right-handed) rotations.

Note that the *typical* choice made by most resources with which I'm familiar is the set $\{K'\}$, e.g. the [wikipedia article on $\mathrm{SO}(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Lie_algebra).

> Note: I do not believe this is simply a matter of convention regarding what is considered a positive angle, handedness of the coordinates, nor the ordering of matrix multiplication for vector operations. All of those are standard in other parts of MTW.

Can you provide an example of a contradiction in MTW?  For instance, is there a passage which says that
$$e^{\theta K_z} = \pmatrix{\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\0&0&1}$$
or something similar?

---

$^\dagger$These commutation relations are computed in Exercise 9.14, so there is not a typo in the text.  It simply uses a different convention.

Comment: The issue is that they claim $\mathcal{R}_{x}\left(\theta\right)$ is a matrix producing a rotation by $\theta$ about the  $x$-axis.  In Box 2.4 positive angles produce ccw rotations.  They don't explicitly write matrix products, but, as far as I know, they always treat a vector as a column, to be placed to the right of the matrix.  Goldstein, Poole and Safco, 3rd Ed. equations 4.79 are the matrices produced by the definition I proposed.

Comment: If you look closely at Box 2.4, they have $\pmatrix{\overline x\\ \overline y} = \pmatrix{\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\-\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)}\pmatrix{x\\y}$, so the given rotation matrix describes the transformation of **components** under a (passive) change of **basis**. In other words, if you rotate your reference frame by an angle $\theta$, the vector (which doesn't rotate *at all*) "appears" to rotate by an angle $-\theta$.  The elements of $SO(3)$ obtained by exponentiating the $\mathcal K$s similarly tell you how the components of a vector change when the basis is rotated by $\theta$.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton If you exponentiate the $\mathcal K'$s, you obtain the matrices which tell you how the components of a vector change when the basis is left alone and the *vector* is rotated by an angle $\theta$ about the relevant axis.  This is what we would refer to as an active transformation.

Comment: It will take me some time to sort this out.  I now realize they are using a different definition of "generator" than the one I was applying from group theory.  In the meantime, I will assume your interpretation of what they mean by "rotation" is correct.  See the final comment in the answer I posted

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton It's important to remember that the infinitesimal generators of a group are a *choice* of basis for the corresponding Lie algebra.  There are conventional choices which tend to be made in the literature, but there is nothing inherently wrong about making a different choice of infinitesimal generators (which would yield different commutation relations and structure constants).

Comment: I now realize that the "infinitesimal generators" of rotations (generators of $\mathcal{so}\left(3\right)$?) are different from what I was calling the generators of $\mathcal{SO}\left(3\right).$ See Vol 1, Part B, 3.4 of https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-volume-1

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I don't have access to that book, but I assume it defines a generating set of a group to be a collection of elements $\{g_i\}$ such that every element of the group can be written as some finite string of $g_i$'s and their inverses, or something to that effect.  In physics, the phrase "(infinitesimal) generators of a lie group" is conventionally taken to mean a basis for the associate Lie algebra. To further overload the word "generator," a basis is sometimes called a generating set of the vector space (or algebra).

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has indicated an error in my mathematical argument, I will assume that part is correct.  The question thus remains: is this a mistake in MTW, or is it simply adherence to a nonstandard parity?  We might ask Kip Thorne.  Since the other parts of Gravitation adhere to the conventions found in, for example
[Rotations in 3D, so(3), and su(2). *version 2.0* Matthew Foster, September 5, 2016](http://mf23.web.rice.edu/LA_1_v2.0%20Rotations%20in%203D,%20so(3),%20su(2).pdf), I am of the opinion that MTW are in error.  Such a mistake is easy to appreciate, considering that their definition "works".

https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_52.html#Ch52-S8

> So if our Martian is made of antimatter and we give him instructions to make this “right” handed model like us, it will, of course, come out the other way around. What would happen when, after much conversation back and forth, we each have taught the other to make space ships and we meet halfway in empty space? We have instructed each other on our traditions, and so forth, and the two of us come rushing out to shake hands. Well, if he puts out his left hand, watch out!

There is also another possibility.  It depends on what is meant by "rotation".  If we are discussing the transformation of an invariant vector under the rotation of a coordinate system, then MTW's definition is correct.

Comment: Sure your last paragraph is correct. But the generators of the rotating group SO(3) are for rotating a vector. In that way the commutation relation $[K_i , K_j] = \epsilon_{ijk} K_k$.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski That's my spin on the exercise.  Your equation is correct.  But it is not the definition of the generators.   See equation 1.1.6 in the paper I linked in my answer.

Comment: It is not 1.1.5? There the generators are defined in the way to match the commutation relation.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski  Sorry, I meant 1.1.16

Comment: Oh yes. There the permutation order are changed from both sides of the equation, given the correct generators.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Meh!  This is what I get for thinking Wheeler was wrong.  We are all correct.  Except me.  I was wrong that MTW made a mistake.  Their "rotation" is a rotation of coordinates.  Clearly other authors use a different set of definitions for the special rotation group.  You are in agreement with Goldstein, et al., 3rd Ed.  Which is fine company.